# Getting a new "publish to web" URL for a published Google doc

Tags: google-sheets

When I publish a Google spreadsheet to the web, it generates a URL that I can share with others. I know I can stop publishing. When I re-publish, the URL is the same.

I no longer want ALL viewers who have that URL to view my spreadsheet, but I do want some to keep viewing it.  Is there a way to get a new URL or do I have to recreate the entire workbook (it's fairly involved with lots of sheets, so I'd rather not)?

Answer (score 5):

Recreating the entire workbook is actually as simple as performing a "save a copy" operation. You can then publish the copied workbook to get a new unique URL, and share that URL with the people who need it.

A more sophisticated approach is to share for viewing, instead of publishing. This lets you identify a user list, and add or remove users at will.